# datepicker is not working in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, datepicker

My datepicker code is not working in jsp. Below is my code. Please someone help me on this.

```html
<style>
</style>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/onload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--  date picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
     $( ".date" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>
<body>
<div class="popup">
<label>From date </label><input type="date" name="fromdt" id="fromdt" class="date"/><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine in the snippet, although you are including 2 different versions of jQuery. You should remove one. You should also put the reference to `onload.js` *after* including jQuery. We can't debug a problem we don't have information about. If you check the console of your site, what errors do you see?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I am getting only this error at console "ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of null "

Comment: I think error is throwing from js/onload.js file. check the code.